# Wrong assembly version brought with dependency

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have an **assembly_A** that depends on *some_framework* v2.1 from NuGet.
Then I have some **assembly_B** that depends on **assembly_A**, but when I compile the solution, it's the version 2.0 - not 2.1 of *some_framework* that is brought with **assembly_B**.

My guess is that the build has chosen v2.0 because that's the version in my GAC, but I need v2.1... No other dependency uses *some_framework*. Obvious bypass would be to make **assembly_B** depend on *some_framework* v2.1 through NuGet, but that's not very elegant!

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an unique solution? If not, try to use an [nuget config file](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file) to keep the same packages folder for your projects.

My idea to happening this is:

- You installed your depedency on **assembly_A**
- On **assembly_B** (already has reference to **assembly_A**), you using code of the dependency you installed (adding dll on csproj)
- On **assembly_A**, you updated your dependency from nuget, but on **assembly_B** (csproj), the reference continue to old version

Look at **web.config > runtime > assemblyBinding** section the version setted of your dependency

In the latter case, go to the directory of your package and see if its dependence contains different versions. If there is, delete old versions and rebuild your solution for check project references.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.
Actually I think that my assembly B had initially a dependence on v2.0 from the GAC (it's an Azure Worker Role with initial dependence on AzureStorage v2.0 at project creation) and my assembly A has Nuget dependency on AzureStorage v2.1. I checked everything but I keep on getting AzureStorage v2.0 when I compile the Worker Role...

Comment: Try to "enable package restore" on your solution. Maybe on build/publish correct the problem.